# toilet won't drain - appears to be no blockage

Tags: plumbing, toilet, vent

First floot toilet - extremely slow drain, more than 2 hours.
Bath - extremely slow drain, ditto.
Sink - gurgles a bit (also while bath trying to drain) but will drain with cold tap going full blast.

Tried to get a snake through the toilet bends and beyond with little success so I accessed the soil stack by removing the sink waste pipe at their junction and got all 25ft of the snake in and twirled it dementedly with no problem.

Decided that the blockage must be between the toilet and stack in the flexible (concertina type) waste pipe so removed the toilet pan revealing no visible blockage so I snaked again.  The spring head dropped easily all the way and I paid out all of it giving it lots of vigorous twirls on its journey and a good five minutes of twisting when I'd got no more snake left to play with.  On withdrawal there was one clump of long hair which amounted to even less than I've pulled from the bath plughole after I've taken a shower.

Reattached the sink waste and ran the sink to commence clean up before putting the toilet back into position and what looked to be the same amount of water I'd just run came out of the toilet waste pipe and onto the floor.

Bath waste pipe connects to soil stack approx 1 inch above floor level, sink waste connects approx 1 inch above bath waste, toilet waste connects at the level between bathroom floor and downstairs ceiling.

I've wondered if there was a blockage in the stack at roof level and if air pressure might be the cause of the problem but surely having the toilet pan off the waste would have balanced things and therefore there should have been no spillage onto the floor?

Why won't the water go down?

I'd appreciate your insights.  Cheers, Jane

Comment: The blockage is BEYOND the toilet and also beyond where the toilet, sink, and bath drain come together.  I doubt it's the roof vent as you'd get gurgling instead of such slow draining.

Comment: @jwh20: The OP says the sink drains with the cold tap going full blast.

Comment: I didn't get that initially...

The blockage is BEYOND the toilet and also beyond where the toilet and bath drain come together. I doubt it's the roof vent as you'd get gurgling instead of such slow draining.